# Merging 2 csv files - html encoded

Tags: python, html, pandas, encoding

I need to merge 2 csv files by one column called 'name'. Column 'name' has mixed types.

The data is html encoded. File 'a' contains more rows than file 'b'.

My desired output should contain only the names in file 'b'.

**file a**: id_public, name, counts

**file b:** id, name

The data looks like this:

**Names:** Å elomo Ben-Meleá¸µ; A. C. P. M.; Ãlvarez de Paz, Mario *1860-1920*; Aahl, Peter; etc.

I've been able to merge these files but only losing all the rows containing special characters (e.g. my merged file will only contain Aahl, Peter). My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("a.csv", low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv", low_memory=False)

merged = a.merge(b, on='name')
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry don't you want to do `merged = a.merge(b, on='name', how='right')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem had nothing to do with encoding, you just used the wrong type of merge. You wanted to perform a `right` merge:

```
merged = a.merge(b, on='name', how='right')
```

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)